# Proof: Kish's effective sample size is no greater than the number of samples

Tags: statistics, sampling

Given a dataset $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N\}$, and two densities $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with $p(x)$ being absolutely continuous with respect to $q(x)$, the effective sample size is defined as the number of samples from $p(x)$ that would provide an estimator with a performance equal to that of the importance sampling estimator $w(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ with $N$ samples. The [Kish's effective sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_sample_size#Weighted_samples) is defined to be

$$
N_{ESS}={\Vert w(X)\Vert_1^2\over \Vert w(X)\Vert_2^2}={\left(\sum_xw(x)\right)^2\over(\sum_xw(x)^2)}
$$

How can I prove that $N_{ESS}\le N$?

#### Update

I've come up with a solution that utilizes the nonnegativity of variance. I regard $w(x)$ as a random variable $Y$. Then, $\Vert w(X)\Vert_1^2=N^2\mathbb E[Y]^2$ and $\Vert w(X)\Vert_2^2=N\mathbb E[Y^2]$. Because $\mathbb E[Y^2]-\mathbb E[Y]^2=Var(Y)\ge0$, ${\mathbb E[Y]^2\over\mathbb E[Y^2]}\le 1$ and $N_{ESS}\le N$. I'm still open to any analytical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For a given sum $S=\sum_x w(x)$, you can show that you minimise $\sum_xw(x)^2$ when the $w(x)$ are all equal, i.e. all $w(x)=\frac1NS$, the average of the weights

That $\sum_xw(x)^2$ will then give an upper bound on $N_{ESS}$

Comment: Hi, @Henry, Could you please be more specific? I know $N_{ESS}$ is maximized when all $w(x)$s equal. But I have no idea how to prove it. I've updated a solution in my question which resorts to the positivity of variance. But I still want to learn your method!

Comment: @Maybe  It is a consequence of $\sum_x \left(w(x)-\frac1NS\right)^2 \ge 0$ with equality iff each $w(x)=\frac1NS$.  This is much the same as saying variance is non-negative